# method name not printing correctly in log4j logger in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j, method-names

My log happens in `getParam()` method. but it is logged as `main` method. And I have three objects, but I do not see any information as to which object is logging. I want that information too.

Here is the output:

```
INFO  [main]: info
INFO  [main]: debug
INFO  [main]: trace
```

here is the code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

class Log4jTest {

    private static Logger log=Logger.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);
    private String param;

    public Log4jTest(String param){
        this.param=param;
    }

    public String getParam(){
        log.info(param);
        return param;
    }

}

public class Log4j_testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Log4jTest l1= new Log4jTest("info");
        l1.getParam();
        Log4jTest l2= new Log4jTest("debug");
        l2.getParam();
        Log4jTest l3= new Log4jTest("trace");
        l3.getParam();
    }
}
```

my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%t]: %m%n
```

On a different note:
 if I have the above commented line uncommented and the last line commented out, I get

```
11:19:41,586  INFO Log4jTest:19 - info
11:19:41,589  INFO Log4jTest:19 - debug
11:19:41,589  INFO Log4jTest:19 - trace
```

It gives the correct line number(19) that is being logged, but not the correct method.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see anything wrong here?  That's the class name not the method name?

Answer (score 12):

Add `%M` to your pattern. However, as it is stated in the [JavaDoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html): "Generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue. "

Comment: yes that helped. but how do I know which object is logging. In the example above, I have three objects that logs. but how do I get that information?

Comment: I guess this is not possible.

Comment: You could print the thread name(t), but object name is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

There are some cases when some patterns are *ignored* or never logged (`%C`, `%F`, `%l`, `%L`, `%M`). This is true when using asynchronous loggers and asynchronous appenders. Here is what the [user guide for Log4j 2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-users-guide.pdf) has to said about this (see page 217-218):

> If one of the layouts is configured with a location-related attribute
>   like HTML locationInfo, or one of the patterns %C or %class, %F or
>   %file, %l or %location, %L or %line, %M or %method, Log4j will take a
>   snapshot of the stack, and walk the stack trace to find the location
>   information.
>
> This is an expensive operation: 1.3 - 5 times slower for
>   synchronous loggers. Synchronous loggers wait as long as possible
>   before they take this stack snapshot. If no location is required, the
>   snapshot will never be taken.
>
> However, asynchronous loggers need to
>   make this decision before passing the log message to another thread;
>   the location information will be lost after that point. *The
>   performance impact of taking a stack trace snapshot is even higher for
>   asynchronous loggers: logging with location is 30-100 times slower
>   than without location*. For this reason, asynchronous loggers and
>   asynchronous appenders do not include location information by default.
>
> You can override the default behaviour in your logger or asynchronous
>   appender configuration by specifying `includeLocation="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

The doc for [PatteryLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) tells us that `%M` will provide the method name where the logging request was made, but I have not ever been able to get it to work and ended up putting the method name in the log message.